# javac not showing result in windows 10

Tags: java, windows, command-prompt

```
C:\Users>java -version
java version "1.8.0_101" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

C:\Users>echo %path%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath

C:\Users>javac -version
```

My cursor got stuck here as if it is waiting for some inputs. I cannot kill it with ctrl + c also.

Please advise.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I have no idea what to make of this text?

Comment: *Java --version* to check the java version information.not by javac

Comment: Do you get an empty result or a "not recognized ... command"? Do you have **javac.exe** in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin`? Did you open a **new cmd** after you changed the path?

Comment: Yes I am getting empty result. Yes I opened new cmd too but it didn't help

Comment: @Timothy after adding the path in env variable I am not able to compile java file... Command javac itself is not showing any result...

Comment: Do you have **javac.exe** in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin`?  Asking the same question.

Comment: @SanketMakani Yes I have it at the said location

Comment: Try to reinstall JDK. Hope It will solve the problem.

Comment: Yes I did that also.

Comment: What is the output of running `where javac`?

Comment: @Luke Woodward javac  and javac -version    results the same. It is showing nothing. My prompt seems waiting for some input. It seems it is getting into some kind of infinite loop.

Comment: @Pank: that wasn't what I asked you to do.  I asked you to run a specific command line (yes, there is a command called `where`, in case that's what you're confused about).  Instead you have chosen to reiterate what you have already written elsewhere in your question.  That does absolutely nothing at all to help anybody to help you.

Comment: @Luke Woodward  Output is as follows:                                                  'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.                                                                     Yes I wasn't aware of where command...

Comment: Sorry, try `C:\WINDOWS\system32\where javac` instead.

Comment: I got the output as --- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\javac.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Java 8 has some bug to work successfully with Windows 10. After working on all path settings, uninstalls, re-installs, the only successful solution I got is this.
Search for 'javac.exe' inside the C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin folder.
Right click->Properties->Compatibility->Run Compatibility troubleshooter->Try recommended settings. Click Test.. and now run javac command in CMD, it will work. Then 'Save the recommended settings',

It is just that we made javac to run with Windows 8. Finally, I could run java programs now.. :) Still searching if some fix can be available to run it in windows 10 however ;)